# Consuming REST webs services with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I'd like to create an application using Spring MVC. I'm going to use REST API to deal with my database.

My idea is to use Spring's **RestTemplate** in Service layer. Is it a good idea? 
Or is it better to put RestTemplate code directly do DAO?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to create a DatabaseAccessService interface and implement it.

Something like this

```
@Service
public class DatabaseAccessServiceImpl implements DatabaseAccessService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void storeData(Data data){
         ...
         restTemplate.postForObject(...)
         ... 

    }

}
```

From my point of view DAO's should only be used accessing to database via JDBC, JPA, etc. and not service call like REST or SOAP based WebServices.